# Why is there this referencing error for a value that is cloned and/or copied?

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

I can't figure out what is causing this referencing error:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `s1`
   --> src/regexp/mod.rs:538:9
    |
528 |             match s1.step() {
    |                   --------- `s1` is borrowed here
...
538 |         steps
    |         ^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0515`.
error: could not compile `regexp` due to previous error
```

I've made the CharsStep struct Clone and Copy, and on both pushes I've tried both pushing a clone of the object and making an assignment to get a copy and pushing that. I thought I was getting to understand the memory model, but this one has me stuck. What is being borrowed here? Aren't all the references copied (multiple times!) before being added to the steps vector?

I have looked a the suggested reference and it just explains what I know, that I can only return values, not references to local values, but since they are cloned I think they are OK.

```
pub trait Walker {}
    
// used to hold the state at each step in the search walk, and later to build the final result if successful
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct CharsStep<'a> {
    node: &'a CharsNode,
    string: &'a str,
    matched: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> Walker for CharsStep<'a> {}

impl<'a> CharsStep<'a> {
    fn walk(node: &'a CharsNode, string: &'a str) -> Vec<Box<dyn Walker + 'a>> {
        let mut steps = Vec::<Box<dyn Walker>>::new();
        let mut step = CharsStep {
            node,
            string,
            matched: "",
        };
        if node.limit_desc.0 == 0 {
            steps.push(Box::new(step.clone()));
        }

        for i in 1..node.limit_desc.1 {
            let s1 = step;
            match s1.step() {
                Some(s) => {
                    if i >= node.limit_desc.0 {
                        steps.push(Box::new(s.clone()));
                    }
                    step = s.clone();
                }
                None => {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        steps
    }
    
    fn step(&self) -> Option<CharsStep> {
        let len = self.node.string.len();
        if self.string[0..len] == self.node.string {
            Some(CharsStep {
                node: self.node,
                string: &self.string[len..],
                matched: &self.string[..len],
            })
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm surprised there isn't a warning (or even a Clippy lint) about this.

You have forgotten a lifetime annotation, which materially changes the meaning:

```
fn step(&self) -> Option<CharsStep> {
```

This is interpreted as if you had written:

```
fn step<'s>(&'s self) -> Option<CharsStep<'s>> {
```

When you call `step`, a temporary reference is created because `step` takes `&self`. Due to this missing lifetime annotation, the compiler is quite correct to say that you are borrowing data owned by the current function. It can only look at the function signature, and that's what it says.

Since you are actually borrowing data that `self` itself has borrowed, you need to change the lifetime to be the same as the data referenced there, namely `'a` from the impl context:

```
fn step(&self) -> Option<CharsStep<'a>> {
```

Comment: There is an allow-by-default `rustc` lint - https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/lints/listing/allowed-by-default.html#elided-lifetimes-in-paths - which I'd indeed advised to make a warning in most cases for any newly written code.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you. It looks like my understanding of the memory handling still needs to develop some. I'll try to internalize just what this means - but in the meantime I can proceed with my coding.

Answer (score 1):

```rust
fn step(&self) -> Option<Self>
```

Changing the step function signature to this will work.

The error is caused by these lines

```rust
steps.push(Box::new(s.clone()));
step = s.clone();
```

If you try deleting those, your code should work:). But why is this happening?

let's look at the function signature of `step` function.

```rust
fn step(&self) -> Option<CharsStep>
```

It takes a reference to self and returns an owned value. The compiler is made to think that `CharStep` is being generated by the step function, but internally it is just the refernces of whatever was passed to it.
This value is now owned by the `match` block. When you push it into the vector, it does not create a deep clone since it has references, that's why the compiler is saying that steps owns data of this function which was generated by the step function.

as @peter-hall suggested, changing the signature of step function to include the lifetime should work as compiler will know that it has the same lifetime as input values to the walk function and will be valid even after this function exits.